# How do we file complaints about a moderator closing people's posts when he doesn't know better?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, moderators

1. How do we file the complaint?
2. The post is [Shouldn't iOS disallow apps to look at the clipboard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395254/shouldnt-ios-disallow-apps-to-look-at-the-clipboard) being closed by the moderator @nohillside

Even if the question doesn't have any merit, I'd like to know 1. How do we file a complaint if a moderator is misbehaving?

Comment: Thanks for asking here. We got some flags about comments being rude or unkind and will also follow up as needed if that continues. Asking here is the best way to complain IMO since everyone that moderates can weigh in.  Let’s spin off a second question if you need help editing that question or don’t understand why it was voted closed. Answering your “how to complain” seems like a great use for this thread so everyone knows regardless of the merit of any action on the question in question.

Answer (score 5):

You can file a complaint by clicking on the "Contact" link at the bottom of the main page.

Answer (score 2):

I agree - if you’re sure you want to escalate - contacting the stack employees is an avenue to review any action here. Whether it’s moderators like you (you can access moderation tools due to reputation), elected moderators - going outside the community is always available.

I will link to this overall question on how to question moderator abuse:

- [What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused their privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-their-privileges)

The part that might be relevant here is trying to work it out here or with the local moderation team.

> It's often best for you to try to work things out at as low a level as possible. If you have a problem with one moderator, it's faster for you to reach any of the other elected "Diamond Moderators" on your site as they have the most experience with your specific site and may even have seen other actions you have taken that give context to the issue at hand. Sometimes you want to go above someone's head (or even straight to the top) with a complaint or request, but realize that the recipient will wonder why this person with a complaint couldn't resolve it with the team of moderators that were put in place to do just that.